# div text is not aligning to one line after reverting back to original viewport

Tags: html, css

I have simple code

```
<div class="large-11 medium-11 small-11 columns">
     <div class="header=">Product Header</div>
     <div class="id">ID {{Id}}</div>
     <div class="Availability">&nbsp; Availability of products are not guaranteed.</div>
</div>
```

If I reduce the browser size and see in diminished(mobile) viewport I see Availability text is stretched to 2 lines much before I reach actual mobile view port(Though it had enough space to display in one line). How can I make it display in single line?

Once I move to mobile view port I see its displaying in 2 lines which is fine for the screen size, however when I move back view port/browser size back to normal desktop view its still displaying text in 2 lines unless I refresh the page. how can I fix this?

Comment: Following is the CSS:.id {
      font-size: 14px;
      color: #666666;
      line-height: 20px;
      float: left;
    }

    .Availability {
      font-size: 14px;
      color: #666666;
      line-height: 20px;
    }

Comment: Have you worked on using bootstrap or mobile port view

Comment: By the looks of your code you're using some sort of responsive grid framework (Foundation maybe?).  Why not just nest another responsive row to contain those three elements and use the grid's classes to determine how the respond?